# How can we clone a set of one-to-many records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a one-to-many relationship between two tables. Each table has its own identity primary key id. The problem is cloning some ( or for simplicity all ) of records in Table1 and their related records in Table2, then we will make a copy of all of records in Table1 and Table2 in the same Tables.
For example consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    Id          INT IDENTITY,
    OtherData   INT
)
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    Id          INT IDENTITY,
    CategoryId  INT CONSTRAINT FK_Category_Products 
                    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Categories(Id),
    ProductData INT
)
```

How can we make this copy. there is no restriction in how many commands is used, in order making this to be done.

Edit:
The main problem is saving one-two-many relationship between records while they are to be copied.

Example:

```
Categories:                 Products:
|  Id  |  OtherData  |      |  Id  |  CategoryId |  ProductData  |  
|------|-------------|      |------|-------------|---------------|  
|   1  |    10       |      |  11  |    1        |    20         |  
|   2  |    10       |      |  12  |    2        |    30         |
```

After copy we want this data:

```
Categories:                 Products:
|  Id  |  OtherData  |      |  Id  |  CategoryId |  ProductData  |  
|------|-------------|      |------|-------------|---------------|  
|   1  |    10       |      |  11  |    1        |    20         |  
|   2  |    10       |      |  12  |    2        |    30         |  
|   3  |    10       |      |  13  |    3        |    20         |  
|   4  |    10       |      |  14  |    4        |    30         |
```

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: the problem is saving relationship between records in table1 and table2, while we are cloning them.

Comment: `merge caregories ... output inserted.id as new_id, src.id as old_id into @asdf` and use to link newly created products from old_id to new_id

Comment: i cant find any way to relate newly inserted categories to previous categories and relating to them to each other.

Comment: Include some example data, how would tables look before copy and after copy, right now I do not understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ivan Starostin wrote in his comment, the trick is to use `Merge` to populate the parent categories, output the old id and new id into a map table, and use that map table to insert the products:

```
-- Declare the map table 
DECLARE @Map as table
(
    OldId int,
    NewId int
)

-- Duplicate the records of the Categories table
MERGE INTO Categories
USING 
(
    SELECT Id, OtherData 
    FROM Categories 
) As s ON 1 = 0 -- Always not matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (OtherData)
VALUES (OtherData)
OUTPUT s.Id, Inserted.Id
INTO @Map (OldID, NewId); -- Note the output clause

-- Duplicate the records in the Products table (Note the inner join)
INSERT INTO Products (CategoryId, ProductData)
SELECT NewId, ProductData
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN @Map m ON CategoryId = OldId
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, that was what i needed. perfect solution!